# How to Loop Through Table Rows, Return and Remove NULL Values？

Tags: sql, null, dolphindb

I have a table like this:

```
 t=table(1 1 as x, 2 NULL as y)
```

I want to iterate over rows and return a vector that does not contain NULL. Taking the table above as example, I want to get [1,1] and [2]. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the t table to a matrix, transpose the matrix, and then loop through columns.

```
loop(x->x[x.isValid()], t.matrix().transpose())
```

After running the above code on this table, the result is returned as follows.

```
offset  0   1
0   [1,2]   [1]
```